# Marking instance variables @private

Tags: objective-c, private, instance-variables

I've noticed that a lot of Apple's interfaces use `@private` before their instance variable declarations. Is there a good design reason for this, and is it something I should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Private instance variables are used to separate interface from implementation. In Objective-C, since the class declaration *must* show all of the instance variables, there needs to be a way to prevent subclasses from accessing the ones that are part of the internal implementation. Otherwise, other programmers could write code that depends on those internal variables, which would make it impossible for the class designer to make changes to the class internals without breaking existing code.

Looking at it another way, the instance variables that are *not* marked private are part of a contract with the subclass programmer, whereas the ones marked private are not.

This means that instance variables should usually be marked private so that they can only be accessed through their accessor methods, if at all. Otherwise, someone could easily write a subclass of your class, and simply create an accessor to make any instance variable public.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. As for writing a subclass to publicize instance variables, I'm pretty sure that `@private` doesn't protect against categories publicizing them. Thoughts?

Comment: I tried it out, and you are absolutely correct. It seems that categories are given access to all instance variables, including the private ones. I suppose Objective-C still gives you enough rope to hang yourself with if you really want to :)

Comment: You could also still use the runtime functions to grab the ivar. But if you're doing such things, you know it's a dirty hack, unlike innocently depending on a superclass ivar that you thought was reliable.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want subclasses to be able to access the variables, mark them @private.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to declare instance variables in the @implementation section. Such variables are implicitly private. Source: Kochan: *Programming in Objective-C, Fourth Edition*. p. 199. It is thus not true that the class declaration must show all of the instance variables, as stated by e.James.

The only reason for declaring instance variables in @interface is to allow them to be inherited by a derived class (subclass).

Comment: Correct way to do this going forward is to declare it in a Class Extension in the .m file.  This applies for private methods as well as ivars and properties.  A class extension looks like an unnamed category `()`, but has different semantics and capabilities.